# Docker "invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase"

Tags: docker

I keep getting an error when I try to run my docker command.

The error I keep getting is: `docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.`

The command I am running is:

```
docker run
          -itd
          --name media-planner-api-qa
          --restart=always
          -v /home/prj/media_planner_api_logs:/media-planner-api/logs
          -e ENVIRONMENT=qa
          -e FLASK_APP=index.py
          -e DEBUG=False
          -e PROFILE=True
          -e LOCAL_S1_API_ENV=sa1qa21
          -e QA_S1_API_ENV=$QA_S1_API_ENV
          -e PROD_S1_API_ENV=s1
          -e S1_API_BASE_URL=sa1qa21
          -e SERVICE_EMAIL=$SERVICE_EMAIL
          -e SERVICE_NAME=$SERVICE_NAME
          -e SMTP_HOST=$SMTP_HOST
          -e SMTP_USERNAME=$SMTP_USERNAME
          -e SMTP_PASSWORD=$SMTP_PASSWORD
          -e SMTP_PORT=$SMTP_PORT
          -e SMTP_LOCAL=0
          -e WORKER_USERNAME=$WORKER_USERNAME
          -e WORKER_PASSWORD=$WORKER_PASSWORD
          -e AUTH0_CLIENTID_FC=$AUTH0_CLIENTID_FC_QA
          -e AUTH0_SECRET_FC=$AUTH0_SECRET_FC_QA
          -e SUPPORT_EMAIL=email@address.com
          -p 4000:4000
          --network='host'
          72343423423423.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prj/media-planner-api-qa:latest
```

Thanks

Comment: `72343423423423.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prj/` is invalid

Comment: @LinPy Well I dummied the account ID - how is it invalid?

Comment: that must be something like `myrepo.com/myimage:mytag`, you have additional layer `/prj/`

Comment: double-check the command. the repo seems valid. the above command is valid might be the case you are running the different name in accutual command?

Comment: @LinPy It is the repo, using AWS ECR. It gives the URL to use which I copy and paste.

Comment: `aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/Repositories.html

Comment: @Adiii What do you mean by different name in actual command?

Comment: I mean double the name there is nothing invalid in the repo name. try to run `docker run -itd` your full  command seems like there is spaaces in ENV

Comment: This was it, thank you @Adiii - space in one of the ENV variables!

Comment: try to put all ENV in double qoutes `"`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The repository name is valid as per the documentation of [AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/Repositories.html).

One thing that might cause this issue if there any ENV that have space in its value. so try to enclose all the env in double quotes `"`.

Comment: Confirmed, was a space in one of the env variables.

Answer (score 0):

Another cause of this is if you forget to add the -e flag when specifying one of the environment variables:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -e MYSQL_USERNAME='user' 
                           MYSQL_PASSWORD='pass' 
                        -e MYSQL_HOST='host' 
                        -e MYSQL_DATABASE='database'
                        account-id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com/repo-name
```