# docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase. See 'docker run --help' due to parameters?

Tags: docker

I have the error `docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase. See 'docker run --help'.` with my docker command probably related to one or more parameters that are incorrectly specified but I can't find out which one.

If someone could help me that would be great! :)

**My docker command :**

```
docker run -d --restart=always --privileged \
-e REALM= "TEST.LAN" \
-e SEARCH_DOMAIN= "test.lan" \
-e DOMAIN= "TEST" \
-e ADMIN_PASS= "SUPERAdminPass01!" \
-e DNS_FORWARDER= "8.8.8.8" \
-e SERVER_ROLE= "dc" \
-e DNS_BACKEND= "SAMBA_INTERNAL" \
-e SAMBA_PATH= "/var/lib/samba" \
-p 53:53 -p 53:53/udp \
-p 88:88 -p 88:88/udp \
-p 123:123/udp -p 137:137/udp -p 138:138/udp \
-p 139:139 -p 389:389 -p 389:389/udp \
-p 445:445 -p 464:464 -p 464:464/udp \
-p 636:636 -p 3268:3268 -p 3269:3269 \
-v /home/docker/appdata/samba-ad-dc-lib:/var/lib/samba \
-v /home/docker/appdata/samba-ad-dc-etc:/etc/samba \
--network=static-network --ip=172.18.0.10 \
--name dc1 --hostname dc1 samba-ad-dc-ubuntu:latest
```

I've built the image **samba-ad-dc-ubuntu:latest** previously with the command :

```
docker build -t samba-ad-dc-ubuntu .
```

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45682010/596285 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/57955478/596285

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a superfluous space for every environment variable that needs to be removed: change `-e REALM= "TEST.LAN"` to `-e REALM="TEST.LAN"` a.s.o.